# PHP date and time adding hours

Tags: php

I a script which uses the following:

planned start time- time at which was planned to start

planned start date- date at which was planned to start

script total - how long a process should take

script - current point in script

So the way it works is

expected finish = planned start time/date + script total

actual finish = current time/date + (script total - script in hours)-

I am having trouble getting this to work:

```
$currentpoint = $row['script']; //current point
$progress = $row['scriptotal'] - $currentpoint; //gives hours rem till fin

$actdate ="+".$progress." hours";
$actual = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime("".$actdate.""));
echo $actual; // this looks like it working
```

Above is the actual date being working out and it appears to be working
Next is the expected date which I am having trouble with

```
  $date1 = "".$row['planned_start_date']. " " .$row['planned_start_time']."";
    $expdate= "+".$row["scriptotal"]." hours";
    $expectdate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $date1);
    $expecteddate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("".$expdate."");
    echo $expecteddate; // get output but 1970 is year.
```

I get output from both but one is year 1970 ?. Also I get an error in my script : "a non well formed numeric value encountered".

A solution to either help with the above or :

current date time + int (that represents hours) 
 & 
 a date timw + int ( that represents hours) would help. I think my $actual is working.

thanks in advance

Comment: i can't read this question, i am sorry but `planned to start planned start date- date planned date planned etc` oh

Comment: sorry it did not look that way when I was writing it. I have now corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = "".$row['planned_start_date']. " " .$row['planned_start_time']."";
$expectdate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $date1);
```

[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects the second argument to be a unix timestamp (integer) which I can assume `$date1` is not.

```
$expecteddate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("".$expdate."");
```

You're missing a closing `)`. Also using `"".` and `.""` is pretty pointless here.  You also may want to verify that `$row["scriptotal"]` is an integer.  If it returns null or a non-integer, it will fail.